# "Show Code" features (MathML/TeX) in the context menu don't work

Tags: support, bug

***Explanation of issue:***

The option to "Show Source Code" of rendered math blocks/lines doesn't work as expected.

***Steps to reproduce:***

- Right click on any block/line of rendered math on any page and request either the MathML or TeX source code behind the rendering.
- A window flashes. An icon appears and remains on the taskbar. No window in view.

---

*As per request (May 4th '12)*

- No ad-blocking...
- Google Chrome 18; no extensions concerning JS or MathJaX
- Windows 7 32-bit; SP1

*Additional Info:* 
I can bring the pop-up on screen by 'maximizing' it via task-manager then 'snapping' (in Win7) it to either half of the screen. I can't resize it however.

*PS.* I'm waiting for a solution but in the mean time, I don't see any reason to go after the issue so, apart from informing the SE team in the unlikely event the issue has roots in the engine, I thank you humbly for your help and I don't need anything else. If anyone wishes to add anything then it's their call.

Comment: The "LaTeX" on the site is actively rendered by MathJax. Would you expect to be able to view it as source?

Comment: If you right-click on it there is a popup menu that includes options to show the source as either MathML or TeX. M.Na'el, are you saying the problem is that the popup window which appears when you click on one of those options disappears right after it opens? If so that sounds like a bug, I'll make sure someone from SE sees this.

Comment: I'm seeing the popup with window title "MathJax Equation Source" being rendering outside of my viewable desktop, which I then have to manually move (via a [window manager application](http://winsplit-revolution.com/)) back onto my desktop.  Is this the behavior you're also seeing?

Comment: @jarrodD, I guess it's very close although I don't have similar WM's so I can't try it right now. Still, the pop-up does get an icon (active-icon) on the task-bar.

Comment: @DavidZ, That's exactly what happens except that it doesn't close; the pop-up only disappears from the screen but still have a flashing-icon on the task-bar. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Manishearth, It is actually the same problem -from what I see- but I guess I was unlucky enough to choose a very different title thus missing that question while I posted mine.

Comment: Is this on Chrome in Windows, or some other browser/os?  There is a bug in Chrome 18 that causes the "Show Math As" window to not open properly (in several OS) and be completely inaccessible in Windows.  If that is not your situation, can you give additional browser/OS details?